# Django tests loading fixtures auth.group

Tags: django, django-testing

When I run django tests I get the error:

> IntegrityError: Problem installing fixture ... ContentType matching
>   query does not exist.: (auth.group:pk=2) field_value was
>   '[u'add_corsmodel', u'corsheaders', u'corsmodel']'

I get the fixtures by doing

`python manage.py dumpdata --natural-foreign --exclude=contenttypes --exclude=auth.Permission`

How can I solve this? should I exclude some other table?

Comment: If I erase all the Group objects and then do the fixture update, it works correctly.

Comment: How do you load the fixture? There are multiple possible ways to load fixtures in Django. Adding a simple test case that reproduces the error to your question would do the trick.

Comment: @Louis the fixture loads automatically when I run the tests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing Group from your fixture resolves your issue 
because Group depends on [Permission](https://github.com/django/django/blob/c2ecef869ce46349e79c39610cd66a576d78289e/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L112) which depends on [ContentType](https://github.com/django/django/blob/c2ecef869ce46349e79c39610cd66a576d78289e/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L57), both of which were stripped from the export.

Judging from your comments on this question it sounds like you already figured that part out. There is another answer to you question though: Don't use fixtures for test data in Django. Django's documentation suggests you use the `TestCase.setUpTestData` method to setup your test data. Here's the exert from the documentation: ["Tests are more readable and it’s more maintainable to create objects using the ORM."](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/testing/tools/#fixture-loading)

Answer (score 2):

well I tried to do one simple thing to add permissions.
I've created a .json file and put in data.

```
[
  {
    "model": "auth.group",
    "fields": {
      "name": "foo",
      "permissions": [
        29,45,46,47,48 //permission ID's created in auth.group
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "model": "auth.group",
    "fields": {
      "name": "new_grp",
      "permissions": [
        29,45,46,47,48
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

this is my initial permissions that I want to include and then

```
 manage.py loaddata <myJsonFIle>
```

i think in your case it is not able to find the rows or columns in the table that's why it shows IntegrityError